# How do i make a list from this data?

Tags: excel, excel-tables

So i have the following table, how do i quickly make a list of the totals with their paired value, so take this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f45iq.png]

and change it into this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igC0k.png]

So that i can then sort the list by the total and find out which value has the most points, the actually table will have much more data.

Thank you,
Kyle.

Comment: You can simply use HLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is try and select all the data you want to have to go from ´row to column´.
Paste it where you want but select "Paste Special". Select the "Transpose" option and click "OK".

Also watch this video among others:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uV4CvGR6w7E

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, Thank you!